# Raid failed hdd on new server without data lose

Tags: raid

How to connect old raid 1 (failed) hdd to new Dell power edge 720 , without losing data. HDDs are SAS 2x 146 gb. Or how can i get data from these hdds. When connect hdds raid controller only show physical hdds type (SAS) but not showing capacity and status showing failed. Raid is perc H710.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by failed. http://serverfault.com/questions/732167/recover-data-from-raid-1-array-failed/732170#732170

Comment: Does the new PE720 have the same RAID controller, or at least one that's known to be compatible with whatever got written to the disks by the old controller?

Answer (score 2):

If both disks of the RAID have failed, it's entirely possible that you can't restore the data. In that case, you should stop experimenting with the disks yourself and send them in to a proper data recovery firm (and prepare to pay a lot for this). Fiddling around yourself would just decrease the chance the of successful recovery.

Of course, if the data was important, you surely have a backup you can simply restore to new disks ...